# Cytotoxicity of Ru-complexes

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, chemical-biology, medicinal-chemistry

I have a basic question: why are Ru(II)-complexes cytotoxic?

What I know is that depending on the used ligand some of them interact with the DNA either via DNA-pi-stacking (intercalation) or binding in one of its grooves (minor or major groove). Some might even bind irreversibly. In any case, a high affinity of this interaction is necessary as otherwise those "mistakes" were corrected by the DNAs correction mechanism. But why not use other metals? Whats the advantage of Ru(II)?
Sure, the complex should be inert and the metal non toxic, but what is the advantage about Ru? (I know about cis-Pt complexes and its mimicks...) 
Further one could read much about N-containing ligands like bpy for those complexes and about their nice photophysical properties. But all the literature doesn't show up the connection between cytotoxicity tests and the interaction with the DNA and the choice of the ligand.. Please help me in getting a deeper understanding in this!